# Don't understand why keeps on showing a broken picture icon

Tags: python, html, flask, rotation

I am using Flask to try serve a processed image like cropping or transforming it to the user after being processed by my model but always came short because it'd either produce some error.When I used numpy.rot90(), It didn't rotate my image as planned instead i got this.

```
GET/predict/%3CPIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile%20image%20mode=RGB%20size=64x64%20at%200xCE11748%3E HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Here's my code:

```
@app.route('/predict/<filename>')
def predict(filename):
image_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
img = Image.open(image_path)
image_url = url_for('images', filename=filename)
image_mtx = imread(image_path)
image_mtx = image_mtx / 255.
image_mtx = image_mtx.reshape(-1, 64, 64, 3)
predictions = model.predict(image_mtx)

angles = ['0', '180', '270', '90']
angle = [0, 90, 180, 270]

confidence = str(round(max(predictions[0]), 4))
predictions = angles[np.argmax(predictions)]
print(predictions)

#img = img.rotate(1*int(angle)) #Clockwise (positive), to change to anti-clockwise put -1 
#img = numpy.rot90(img)
if confidence >= '0.8':
    if predictions == '270': angle = 90 
    elif predictions == '180': angle = 180 
    elif predictions == '90': angle = 270
    elif predictions == '0' : angle = 0

numpy.rot90(img)

return render_template(
    'predict.html',
    image_url=image_url,
    img=img,
    predictions=predictions,
    confidence=confidence
)
```

html file:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block body %}
<div class="centered">

<p>Image Given</p>
<img src="{{image_url}}" name="image_url" id="image_url">
<p>Looks like it's {{confidence|safe }}</p>
<p>The picture is rotated at {{ predictions|safe }} degrees</p>
<p>Fixed Image</p>
<img src="{{img}}" name="img" id="img">
</div>
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.10.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets- 
0.12.10.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to produce a valid URL for the rotated image which returns an image file. For this, save the rotated image first. Then you can use `url_for` to produce an URL for it, like for the original image.

Below is a working implementation. I removed the prediction code for readability & to be able to run it on my end. You'll need to replace `uploads` in `os.path.join` with `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']` in your case.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, send_file
from PIL import Image
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/images/<filename>')
def images(filename):
    image_path = os.path.join('uploads', filename)
    return send_file(image_path)

@app.route('/predict/<filename>')
def predict(filename):
    image_path = os.path.join('uploads', filename)
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    image_url = url_for('images', filename=filename)

    # rotate image 90 degrees and save rotated image
    fixed_img = img.rotate(90)
    fixed_img.save(os.path.join('uploads', 'fixed_' + filename))
    fixed_image_url = url_for('images', filename='fixed_' + filename)

    img.close()

    return render_template(
        'predict.html',
        image_url=image_url,
        img=fixed_image_url
    )

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    app.run(port = 8000)
```

Output:

[image: Code output in browser showing original image and rotated image]

Comment: i have another question, image_path = os.path.join('uploads', filename) in the predict function takes it the input first?or is it image_path = os.path.join('uploads', filename) from images function that does?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Oh my bad, I was trying to understand the process actually. Like why do we need to put `image_path = os.path.join('uploads', filename)` in the **images function** if `image_path` is in the **predict function** ?

Comment: Edit: Seems as though it doesnt actually make a difference, i just tested it. Although now i am encountering another problem; just whether or not a float or list is obtained but ill try to solve that on my own. Thanks a lot! I appreciate the help

Comment: The `image` function takes a filename (eg. `dogo.PNG`), loads the file from the uploads folder (eg. `uploads/dogo.PNG`) and returns an image file. When you load `images/dogo.PNG` in the browser, it'll show the image. We use this for the `img src` attribute in the HTML, since the `src` needs a link to the image.

Comment: So in the HTML you will have eg. `<img src="images/dogo.PNG"...` which will call the `images` function and return the image file.

Comment: The `predict` function returns the HTML file containing the image links, not an image.

Comment: but doesn't the `predict` function do it too?(the first line of code). I remember trying something similar to this but i didnt get anything (maybe because I forgot to return it in the `render_template`). Also I thought `nump.rot90` rotated the image, but apparently from the docs, it's the matrix. Interesting.                              I just tried commenting the image function part of the code and it still works.

Comment: Yes, the `predict` function loads the image from the uploads folder in order to process (rotate it). It saves the rotated image, and then creates links to the original and new image like this `images/dogo.PNG` and `images/fix_dogo.PNG`. It then fills those links into the HTML template so that the images can be displayed on the `/predict` page in the browser.

Comment: oh! i see, that makes sense then. The important part is the HTML to obtain the url_link.Thanks a bunch! I was more drawn to the loading the url, i forgot the html needs a url in order to display. I need to do more reading up then

Comment: The code breaks on my end if I remove the `images` function (as it should). Are you sure you're not running multiple instances of the program? `url_for('images', filename=filename)` will fail without an `images` function defined.

Comment: Ah, I see. Mine definitely broke too when i removed the images function. I meant I just commented outthese lines `image_path = os.path.join('uploads', filename)` `return send_file(images_path)` in the `image` function. It still works though.

Comment: If you comment out those lines, the code will run fine but the images will not be displayed in the browser since `img src="images/dogo.PNG"` will no longer return any image to display. Clear the cache or do a hard refresh in your browser (Ctrl + F5).

Comment: i just cleared my cache and tried it again. It still works. I think I may have to restart my computer because I agree with you, it will definitely fail without that line. Exactly! it won't display anything.I just want to take the time to thank you. I appreciate the help you just gave me and the conversation we had.